# Enter sends focus to another textbox but not working properly

Tags: vb.net

Well, I need an help now, I made my own textboxex class by inheriting the textbox field and I am facing a problem now..

I made like when textbox gets focus, its colour changes and when it leave focus, it colour changes back to white. But I don't have any problem with this one.

I also try to add an enter event like when I press enter/return key, the focus goes to next textbox...

here is my code..

```
Public Class textboxex
Inherits TextBox

Private Sub TextBoxEx_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Enter'This is for color and works fine
    Me.BackColor = Color.Cyan
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxEx_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Leave'This is for color and works fine
    Me.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
 'Problem is with this below...
Private Sub TextBoxEx_Return(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
       If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Now I have a little problem with textboxex_return sub...

The problem is when I start the form, the focus goes directly to button present in the form.

On debugging I found that every textbox takes enter/return key automatically when it get focus..

I tried to handle with different events like keydown,keypress,textchanged etc but cannot do it...

I don't know if this thing possible, or I have to write this "e.keycode = keys.enter" in every sub...

Plz help plox ...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button has a lower tab index. 
Change the tab index of the first textbox1 to zero and it will work.
And if it doesn't suit you you could do this in the form load.
Textbox1.focus ()
☺

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to set TabIndex for this. set tabindex of textbox is 1. 
2) you can use TabOrder Also in your designing page .
   **-->Menu --> View --> Tab Order  ** 
   Set Tab order and check it.
3) If Both steps not working then setFocus() from coding.

Comment: I set all the tab Index before only..
Tab Index are proper, it just takes enter automatically on getting focus on every textbox

Comment: Oh I got it, it was just 1 silly mistake...
My code is proper and 100% working fine...!!!
Thanx guys...